# Finder copying dialog freezing from time to time during transfer

Tags: finder, hard-drive, backup, file-transfer

I'm trying to backup 2tb drive I have connected to my mac to another drive using this enclosure via firewire 800: http://eshop.macsales.com/item/OWC/M3QX2KIT0GB/


The problem is that from time to time the copying dialog is freezing and not doing enything. During that time I can see my hard drive also I can se all the folder in root folder but when I open them, they are all empty. As soon as finder resume from that freezing stage I can access anything on that drive.

 Some time the freezing las longer and I've got an error that a certain file was unable to be copied but when I searched for it and trying to copy it manually it worked. Du

During the freezing the hdd leds just said open without blinking.

 I've tried DiskUtilty's First Aid (notice that I'm using El Captain) and everything seems ok. 

 Tried also:

> diskutil repairdisk /dev/diskx

but everything seems fine.

I Have also noticed a slow transfer rating. 2tb in more than 1 day.

Any Ideas why is that happening.

There are any other method to backup those files without finder?

Comment: You should be using the command-line `cp` command. `cp` bypasses all the Finder overhead and just moves the data. Using `cp` is recommended when moving thousands (or hundreds of thousands) of files/folders.

Comment: could you give me a hint how to use it?

Comment: `cp <source> <destination>`  Ex: `cp /Desktop/Folder_of_files /External_Drive/Folder_Destination`   The command `man cp` in Terminal will give you all the switches and options. [This page](http://www.macworld.com/article/2080814/master-the-command-line-copying-and-moving-files.html) gives some additional help. I suggest you experiment with the `cp` command to see how it works.